# How to fixed objects with background?

Tags: android

I'm going to show the number of textview  and buttons In a background photo
But they are not in  fixed locations In different screens
How can this problem be solved in xml

[photo1](http://s9.picofile.com/file/8289340200/android1.png)

[photo2](http://s9.picofile.com/file/8289340218/android2.png)

Comment: post your xml here

Answer (score -1):

First of all, read about LinearLayout and RelativeLayout

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

With RelativeLayout you can fix the textviews' position.